# regex in sed removing only the first occurrence from every line

Tags: regex, bash, sed, non-greedy

I have the following file I would like to clean up

`cat file.txt`

```
MNS:N+    GYPA*01 or GYPA*M   
MNS:M+    GYPA*02 or GYPA*N
MNS:Mc    GYPA*08 or GYP*Mc
MNS:Vw    GYPA*09 or GYPA*Vw
MNS:Mg    GYPA*11 or GYPA*Mg
MNS:Vr    GYPA*12 or GYPA*Vr
```

My desired output is:

```
MNS:N+  GYPA*01 or GYPA*M   
MNS:M+  GYPA*02 or GYPA*N
MNS:Mc  GYPA*08 or GYP*Mc
MNS:Vw  GYPA*09 or GYPA*Vw
MNS:Mg  GYPA*11 or GYPA*Mg
MNS:Vr  GYPA*12 or GYPA*Vr
```

I would like to remove everything between ":" and the first occurence of "or"

I tried `sed 's/MNS:d*?or /MNS:/g'` though it removes the second "or" as well.

I tried every option in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/

to no avail. should I create `alias sed='perl -pe'`? It seems that sed does not properly support regex

Comment: Another approach with GNU sed: `sed -r 's/:.{14}/:/' file`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perl` should be more suitable here because we need Lazy match logic here.

```
perl -pe 's|(:.*?or +)(.*)|:\2|' Input_file
```

by using `.*?or` we are checking for the first nearest match for or string in the line.

Comment: Are there any advantages to using sed over perl -pe overall?

Comment: @user171558, if its a single character then we could have used back reference logic in sed but in perl you can do lazy match(which means look for nearest match first).

Comment: No downvote from me. Shorter: `perl -pe 's/:.*? or /:/' file`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/:.*\<or\>/{s/\<or\>/\n/;s/:.*\n//}' file
```

If a line contains `:` followed by the word `or`, then substitute the first occurrence of the word `or` with a unique delimiter (e.g.`\n`) and then remove everything between `:` and the unique delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

Wrt `I would like to remove everything between ":" and the first occurence of "or"` - no you wouldn't. The first occurrence of `or` in the 2nd line of sample input is as the start of `orweqqwe`. That text immediately after `:` looks like it could be any set of characters so couldn't it contain a standalone `or`, e.g. `MNS:2 or eqqwe or M+    GYPA*02 or GYPA*N`

Given that and the fact it's apparently a fixed number of characters to be removed on every line, it seems like this is what you should really be using:

```
$ sed 's/:.\{14\}/:/' file
MNS:N+    GYPA*01 or GYPA*M
MNS:M+    GYPA*02 or GYPA*N
MNS:Mc    GYPA*08 or GYP*Mc
MNS:Vw    GYPA*09 or GYPA*Vw
MNS:Mg    GYPA*11 or GYPA*Mg
MNS:Vr    GYPA*12 or GYPA*Vr
```

Comment: You should REALLY change `MNS:2 odwasdsw or M+    GYPA*02 or GYPA*N` to `MNS:2 or asdsw or M+    GYPA*02 or GYPA*N` in your example if that can occur because most solutions posted so far will fail if/when it does.

Answer (score 1):

If it is sure the `or` always occurs twice a line as provided example, please try:

```
sed 's/\(MNS:\).\+ or \(.\+ or .*\)/\1\2/' file.txt
```

Result:

```
MNS:N+    GYPA*01 or GYPA*M   
MNS:M+    GYPA*02 or GYPA*N
MNS:Mc    GYPA*08 or GYP*Mc
MNS:Vw    GYPA*09 or GYPA*Vw
MNS:Mg    GYPA*11 or GYPA*Mg
MNS:Vr    GYPA*12 or GYPA*Vr
```

Otherwise using `perl` is a better solution which supports the `shortest match` as RavinderSingh13 answers.

Answer (score 1):

`ex` supports lazy matching with `\{-}`:

```
ex -s '+%s/:\zs.\{-}or //g|wq' input_file
```

The pattern `:\zs.\{-}or` matches any character after the first `:` up to the first `or`.